# I encounter a memory issue whenever i try to split a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, operating-system

I am writing a kernel in c. I am trying to write a split string function that takes in a string (char s[]), a delimiter (char d), and a pointer to a 2 dimensional output array (char** outp) that returns the length of items written to outp. For reference, I terminated all strings with '\n'. The problem occurs when I try to read from outp after calling split, it returns unexpected values. However, when I read outp inside the split function, the split string array value is correct.

For demo purposes, i am going to split "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" with a space character.

EDIT: I tried allocating memory for it.

Here's the output from inside the split function

```
The
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog
```

Here's the output from printing outp after calling split.

```
9
lazy
the
the
quick
the
the
brown
the
```

Edit: Here's the memory allocator function

````c
u32 free_mem_addr = 0x10000;
u32 kmalloc(u32 size, int align, u32 *phys_addr) {
    /* Pages are aligned to 4K, or 0x1000 */
    if (align == 1 && (free_mem_addr & 0xFFFFF000)) {
        free_mem_addr &= 0xFFFFF000;
        free_mem_addr += 0x1000;
    }
    /* Save also the physical address */
    if (phys_addr) *phys_addr = free_mem_addr;

    u32 ret = free_mem_addr;
    free_mem_addr += size; /* Remember to increment the pointer */
    return ret;
}

Edit: Here's where I allocated the memory
```c
output = (char**)kmalloc(MAX_ARG_COUNT * MAX_ARG_SIZE, 1, (u32*)&output);
````

````
Here's the input handler in the kernel.
```c
void handle_input(char* input) 
{
    char** output;
    int arg_len = split(input, ' ', output);
    kprint("\n");
    char str[5];
    int_to_ascii(arg_len, str);
    kprint(str);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arg_len; i++)
    {
        kprint(output[i])
    }
    kprint("\n$> ");
}
````

Here's the split string function

```c
int split(char s[], char d, char** outp)
{
    int i;
    int size = 0;
    int buffer_size = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == d)
        {
            outp[size][buffer_size] = '\0';
            kprint(outp[size]);
            kprint("\n");
            size++;
            buffer_size = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            outp[size][buffer_size] = s[i];
            buffer_size++;
        }
    }
    kprint(outp[size]);
    return size+1;
}
```

Comment: `output` is uninitialized. You'll have to allocate some memory and assign `output` to point to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)